# How to find the sum of three separate numbers in a string using java?

Tags: java, string

I have a below string:

```
String Str = "passed=20 failed=15 skipped=10";
```

From that I need find the sum of

- `passed`
- `failed`
- `skipped`

Comment: 1) split on space. 2) split on equals. 3) take the second item of each of the second splits. 4) parse them to a number. 5) sum.

Comment: split on regexp to use anything but digit as separator, convert then strings to integers.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\s").splitAsStream(input).map(kv -> kv.split("=")[1]).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()`.

Comment: Regex is good for this

Answer (score 4):

Use regex `\\d+` find all numbers in the string, then parse and sum them:

```
String example = "passed=20 failed=15 skipped=10";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
int sum = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
}
System.out.println(sum);
```